Ruby on Rails hashed password using BCrypt not saving to postgres users table
I am trying to hash a password using bcrypt-ruby and save it to a postgres users table but I cannot get the hash to save properly. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? This is what I have tried:
User Model:
require 'bcrypt'

class User < ApplicationRecord
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
  include BCrypt

  has_secure_password

  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessor :password_digest

  enum :user_type, { :registered => 1, :administrator => 2 }



  validates :email, presence: true

  validates_format_of :email,  with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP 
  validates :password_digest, presence: true
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

end

Rails Migration:
class User < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  create_table :users do |t|
    t.string :username,           null: false, default: ""
    t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
    t.string :password_digest,    null: false, default: ""


    t.string :user_type,          default: 'registered'


    t.timestamps null: false
  end

  add_index :users, :username,             unique: true
  add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
  add_index :users, :user_type

end

Rails Console:
include BCrypt

@user = User.new
@user.username = "test123456"
@user.email="test123456@gmail.com"
@user.user_type = 1
@user.password = "test123456"
@user.password_digest = Password.create("test123456")
@user.password_confirmation = "test123456"
@user.save!

Generated SQL in Rails Console:
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("username", "email", "password_digest", "user_type", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["username", "test123456"], ["email", "test123456@gmail.com"], ["password_digest", "[FILTERED]"], ["user_type", "1"], ["created_at", "2024-10-03 13:53:37.193227"], ["updated_at", "2024-10-03 13:53:37.193227"]]
  TRANSACTION (0.8ms)  COMMIT

Postgres:


what exactly is the problem with the save?

The hashed password is not saving to the postgres table while everything else does

You need to remove these two line from your User model:
attr_accessor :password
attr_accessor :password_digest

Because those are overriding the getter and setter models that are created automatically by Ruby and Rails.
And I suggest changing
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

to
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, on: :create

Because the password_confirmation is only set when the user sets or updates the password. When the user, for example, want to change their email, the password_confirmation would be blank, because it is not stored to the DB.

Thank you! Great spot! I needed a second set of lenses on this. I think I got stuck in an outdated set of documentations / how-tos  and updated ruby on rails version set of features.
